# Flutter image_gallery_saver returns wrong file path on Android

Tags: flutter

I'm using [image gallery saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) to save an image to the user's device and get the file path back to store in a DB so I can use the image in the app. This works fine on iOS, but on Android, it gives me back this file path:

```
filePath: content://media/external/images/media/1000006846
```

And when trying to use this path in an image widget, I get this error:

```
'content://media/external/images/media/1000006846' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Comment: Are you hardcoding a file path? If yes, then use the path_provider package to get the path. Otherwise, have you given the permissions to your app as instructed by the package: <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .....>

Comment: no the file path is returned by the lib mentioned in the OP

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Were you able to find a solution? If yes, please help me with this.